# Inverse filtering using Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, sympy

Given an impulse response `h` and output `y` (both one-dimensional arrays), I'm trying to find a way to compute the inverse filter `x` such that `h * x = y`, where `*` denotes the convolution product.

For example, suppose that the impulse response `h` is `[1,0.5]`, and the output is a step function (that is, consists of all `1`s). One can figure out that the first coefficients should be `[1, 0.5, 0.75]`, which yields an output of `[1, 1, 1, 0.375]`. The last term contains an error, but this is not really an issue as I'm only concerned with the output up to a certain maximum time.

I would like to automate and 'scale up' this inverse filtering to a longer, more complex impulse response function. So far, the only way I've figured out to get the coefficients is by generating the series expansion of the Z-transform using sympy. (Note that the Z-transform of a step function is 1/(1-z)).

However, I've noticed that sympy is quite slow in computing the coefficients: it takes 0.8 seconds even for a simple, short example, as demonstrated by the script below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from sympy import Symbol, series
import time

h = np.array([1,0.5])           # Impulse response function
y = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])       # Ideal output is a step function

my_x = np.array([1,0.5,0.75])   # Inverse filter response (calculated manually)

my_y = signal.convolve(h,my_x)  # Actual output (should be close to ideal output)

print(my_y)

start = time.time()
z = Symbol('z')
print(series(1/((1-z)*(1+z/2)),z))
end = time.time()
print("The power series expansion took "+str(end - start)+" seconds to complete.")
```

This produces the output:

```
[ 1.     1.     1.     0.375]
1 + z/2 + 3*z**2/4 + 5*z**3/8 + 11*z**4/16 + 21*z**5/32 + O(z**6)
The power series expansion took 0.798881053925 seconds to complete.
```

In short, the coefficients of the power expansion match the desired filter response, but it seems cumbersome to me to use sympy to do this. Is there a better way to compute inverse filter coefficients in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called deconvolution: [scipy.signal.deconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.deconvolve.html) will do this for you. Example where you know the original input signal `x`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal

# We want to try and recover x from y, where y is made like this:
x = np.array([0.5, 2.2, -1.8, -0.1])
h = np.array([1.0, 0.5])
y = signal.convolve(x, h)

# This is called deconvolution:
xRecovered, xRemainder = signal.deconvolve(y, h)
# >>> xRecovered
# array([ 0.5,  2.2, -1.8, -0.1])
# >>> xRemainder
# array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
#          0.00000000e+00,  -1.38777878e-17])

# Check the answer
assert(np.allclose(xRecovered, x))
assert(np.allclose(xRemainder, 0))
```

It sounds like you don’t know the original signal, so your `xRemainder` will *not* be 0 to machine precision—it’ll represent noise in the recorded signal `y`.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. Indeed in my example, if I use `decon_x, remainder = signal.deconvolve(y,h)`, I get the result `decon_x = [1., 0.5, 0.75, 0.625]`, which are exactly the leading order terms of the series expansion of the Z-transform I derived.