# extracting signal from a sum of two signals shifted in time

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing, shift

I have a signal (Sout(t)) which is a sum of two (almost) identical signals (S) shifted by a known delay dt:

```
Sout(t) = S(t)+S(t-dt)
```

How do I reconstruct the original S(t)? I program in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a effectively a signal that passed through a FIR-filter. The FIR-filter will have a response h[n] of the form [1,0,0,0,0,1] where the number of zeros should be (dt*f_sampling -1).

According to this post you can do inverse filtering on such signals using scipy standard functions:
[inverse-filtering-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146985/inverse-filtering-using-python)

Comment: this FIR filter works pretty well, but it introduces an additional frequency in the signals which corresponds to the length of the response function. But thanks!

Comment: Please accept the answer if you like it.

Comment: I guess such extra frequencies are to be expected. I can imagine that padding the beginning and end of Sout with len(h) zeros would reduce them. But that is gut feeling, I would have to think about a justification for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is many methods you can implement, Fourier transfom may be the best one, since you know the delay we can formulate this probelem as following :

```
I- Apply the fourier transfrom :

F(Sout(t)) = F(S(t)) + F(S(t-dt))

 Note : 
 1. F(Sout(t)) -> Sfout(f)
 2. F(S(t)) -> Sf(f)

II- Extract Sf(f) :

Sfout(f) = Sf(f) + Sf(f) * exp(-j2*pi*f*dt)
Sfout(f) = Sf(f) * (1 + exp(-j2*pi*f*dt))
Sf(f) = Sfout(f) / (1 + exp(-j2*pi*f*dt))

III- Apply inverse fourier transfrom to get S(t) :

S(t) = InvF(Sfout(f) / (1 + exp(-j2*pi*f*dt)))
```

In python you can call the fast fourier transfrom using `Sfout = np.fft.fft(Sout)`
For the inverse run this one `S = np.fft.ifft(Sfout)`

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I'm trying to follow your example, but I have never done any calculations with complex numbers in python. How do I implement the following line:

```
Sf(f) = Sfout(f) / (1 + exp(-j2*pi*f*dt)) ?
```

Comment: OK, I've found the correct way of implementing your algorithm, however it does not give correct result. The reconstructed signal looks like Sout with half of amplitude not S.